# Apple developer (HIG) links not allowed?

Tags: bug

The other day I suddenly get this error when I am linking a HIG link. Never had the problem earlier.

[image]

Have there been some changes or something?

Comment: I just saved your post without the Bit.ly link, seems to have gone through fine. Maybe just a temp glitch? But definitely not something that's supposed to happen

Comment: Looks like a temporary glitch now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not on the list of blacklisted links (and to be honest I would have been very surprised if it was). I've also just tested posting some links to the HIG myself on the main site (I've now deleted those posts).

The links I tested were:

- http://developer.apple.com/library
- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html

I'm not seeing any issues there either as I was able to post those in an answer and as part of a question on the main site with no issues. I can only assume the link was temporarily blacklisted for some reason and has now been re-allowed (although I will look to confirm that). What was the *specific* URL you were trying to post?

Comment: Had the problem here, http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/40092/should-users-be-able-to-scroll-a-web-page-while-a-modal-is-active/40100#40100, later was able to get it to work.

Comment: @rk sorry, I meant what was the HIG URL you were trying to post? Was it one of those I tried above or something else?

Comment: It was the one I used in the answer. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html But, like Ben mentioned it looks like it was a temporary thing.